# Chart.js - Changing value of hover labels

Tags: chart.js

I made a line chart. And in that chart, the Y-axis values are shown as specific text. (Win, Draw, Lose)
Please check my 'yAxes option' code below :

...

```
ticks: {
  min : 1,
  max : 3,
  stepSize : 1,
  callback: function(label, index, labels) {
    switch (label) {
      case 1:
        return 'Lose';
      case 2:
        return 'Draw';
      case 3:
        return 'Win';
    }
  }
}
```

...

Currently, Y-axis value is shown in hover labels.
I want to show the text(Lose, Draw, Win) instead of Y-axis value in hover labels.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a customised callback for the tooltips i.e. in this case no title on tooltip just the axis label..

```
tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                  return '';
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                }
              }
      },
```

Comment: Be sure to put this code inside the `options: {`.

Comment: note that the height of the tooltip won't expand if you want to put many lines of text (like more than 10 or 20)